# Json parsing the right way when you have a single value on it

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have a jquery function that sends some data to a method and receives a simple json from the php (the json returns the data sent through get).

```
$("#filter").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({                                        
            data:$("form").serialize(),                 
            type: $(this).attr("get"),                  
            url:"get.php",                              
            success: function(response){                
                $("#rez").html(response);               
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
```

This is the json I get

```
{"list1":["bike","car","bus"],"list2":["1 seat","4 seas","10 seats"],"list3":["cheap","medium","expensive"],"list4":["green energy","bio","petrol"]}
```

I tried to iterate through it like this:

```
$.each(response, function(index, val)
                {
                    alert(response[index]);
                    });
```

Also, tried this:

```
alert(val);
```

How can I iterate through it and make a simple alert?
The goal is to append each item to the "#rez" paragraph. But for now, I just want to iterate through the json and can't figure it out.

ALSO!
I have another json like this:`["first val","second val"]` how do I iterate this? Tried the above methods and none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start to loop you have to parse the `JSON string` into an `Object` and in this case you can do it using something like this:

```
var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);

$.each(obj, function(index, val) {
    // ...
});
```

If you don't provide the data type like `dataType:"json"` in your `ajax` params object then you have to explicitly parse the string to an object. [Read more abour $.parseJSON here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

Comment: Yes, this is the reason it didn't work. Thanks a lot! But I have one more question. if I have a php that makes a select (select type, nrSeats, price, fuel from auto)
how do I create the json properly in php?
`$response[0].type = "car";` and do it for all properties?

Comment: Try `console.log(response)` and check the result in browser console.

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in" at line 5 (this is line 5: `$response[0].type= "car";`)

Comment: Would upvote your comment, but I have 12 / 15 points to do it so till I get another upvote, I can't do that (if it matters :( )

Comment: Click on the `tick` beneath the answer (only one answer per question) if it solves the actual problem.

Comment: That's what I mean. To build the json properly, shall I create a class and add an object to the answer array, or how to set each property? (type, fuel, etc...)?

Comment: Once I get the json issue done in php as well, you bet you'll get that as well :)

Comment: In `PHP` you create the `json` using `json_encode($dataArray)` which is not your problem. Btw, One question at a time.

Comment: Yep, I know the `json_encode(...)` one. That is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and used this:

```
for (var key in someObject) {
  if (someObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     var something = someObject[key];
     console.log(something)
  }
}
```

Basically using "for"-loop here.

Comment: No `JSON String` is not iterateable until it is turned into an `Object`.